# FTP create path with MKD command

Tags: ftp

I need to store a file on a FTP server using commands. For example FolderA/FolderB/FolderC/myfile.txt. Do I need to create each folder step by step? That would be:
MKD FolderA
MKD FolderB
MKD FolderC
STOR FolderA/FolderB/FolderC/myfile.txt

Or is there a quicker/better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some servers understand complex paths, but the standard way is to create them one by one:

```
MKD FolderA 
CWD FolderA 
MKD FolderB 
CWD FolderB 
MKD FolderC 
CWD FolderC
STOR myfile.txt
```

Comment: This seems to be the only working solution in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

yes you can use `mkd folder1/folder2/folder3` and it will create the whole tree. the same option exists on windows with mkdir

Comment: This doesn't work in my case, I have to create folder by folder